# Stop javascript Date function from changing timezone offset

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

So I have iso date time that need to be converted from a string to date object. How do I keep date from converting it to local browser timezone.

```
new Date('2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00')
Thu Jul 18 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

I want to get

Thu Jul 18 2013 17:00:00 GMT-0500 (XX)

Comment: The point of ISO formatted dates are to be converted back into your timezone...

Comment: You cannot. JavaScript `Date` object do not store any timezone information, and when outputting/toStringing/logging them they will either use your local browser timezone (unfortunately default) or UTC (with explicit methods).

Comment: But what if what I am trying to display is not in the browsers timezone. Why cant date parse string and set the date object to the timezone offset specified in the iso string.

Comment: If you use UTC/GMT, there is toUTCString() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate%2FtoUTCString

Comment: I've just run into this and FireFox doesn't mess with my dates but all the other browsers do.

Comment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/ ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Javascript feels so dumb sometimes. This is one of those moments.

Answer (score 8):

While MomentJS is a great library, it may not provide a solution for every use case.  For example, my server provides dates in UTC, and when the time portion of the date is not saved in the db (because it's irrelevant), the client receives a string that has a default time of all zeros - midnight - and ends with an offset of `+0000`.  The browser then automatically adjusts for my local time zone and pulls the time back by a few hours, resulting in the previous day.

This is true with MomentJs as well.

One solution is to slice off the time portion of the string, and then use MomentJS as described in the other answers.

But what happens if MomentJS is not a viable option, i.e. I already have many places that use a JS Date and don't want to update so many lines of code? The question is how to stop the browser from converting dates based on local time zone in the first place.  And the answer is, when the date is in ISO format, you cannot.

*However*, there is no rule that says the string you pass to JavaScript's Date constructor must be in ISO format.  If you simply replace the `-` that separates the year, month, and day with a `/`, your browser will *not* perform any conversion.

In my case, I simply changed the format of the Dates server-side, and the problem was solved without having to update all the client-side JS dates with MomentJS.

Note that the MDN docs for JavaScript's Date class warn about unpredictable browser-behavior when parsing a string to create a Date instance.

Comment: I had a similar problem, local times that shouldn't be converted, for submission to a server in a different timezone. My solution was to append ".local" to the time string when prepped for transport. It's very obvious when looking at all debugging and logs that this was an unparsable time that was intended to represent the local time at some particular store.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot change this behavior of Javascript because it is the only simple way for Javascript to work. What happens is simply that Javascript looks at the time shift, computes the matching timestamp, and then asks the OS for the representation of this timestamp in the local time zone. What is key to understand here is that `-05:00` is not an indication of time zone but simply a shift from UTC.

Time zones are complex beasts that are just arbitrary political decisions. The OS provides a service to display time in the local time zone, but not in other time zones. To do that you have to take in account things like DST that are pretty much a hell.

As always with time management, the only decent way to tackle this problem is to use a dedicated library. In Javascript, you'll find [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and [Moment.Timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) very helpful.

Example http://codepen.io/Xowap/pen/XKpKZb?editors=0010

```
document.write(moment('2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00').tz('America/New_York').format('LLL'));
```

As a bonus, you get a ton of formatting/parsing features from Moment.js.

Please also note that as long as you use the ISO 8601, your date can be pinpointed to a precise moment, and thus be displayed in any timezone of your liking. In other words, JS "converting" your date doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a library such as **Moment.js** to do this.

See the **String + Format parsing**.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

The following should parse your date you provided, but you may need to modify it for your needs.

```
var dateString = "2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00";

var dateObject = moment(dateString, "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ").toDate();
```

Alternatively, see Moment's String parser, which looks like it is in the format you provided, with the exception of a space between the seconds of the time and the time zone.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question that recently got linked in an answer to a newer question, but none of the existing answers seem to fully address the original question.

In many cases the easiest way to format and display a datetime string in the time zone that it is received, is not to convert the string to a `Date` object at all. Instead, just parse the datetime string and recombine the parts into the desired format. For example, if you can live without the day of the week in the output requested in the question, you could do something like the following to handle the requested input and output format (including the day of the week adds enough complexity that it might be worth using a library at that point). Of course, this approach requires modification based on the format of the datetime strings you are receiving on the client side.

```js
const months = {1: 'Jan', 2: 'Feb', 3: 'Mar', 4: 'Apr', 5: 'May', 6: 'Jun', 7: 'Jul', 8: 'Aug', 9: 'Sep', 10: 'Oct', 11: 'Nov', 12: 'Dec'};
const format = (datetime) => {
  const [date, time] = datetime.split('T');
  const [y, m, d] = date.match(/\d+/g);
  const [t, tz] = time.split(/(?=[+-])/);
  return `${months[Number(m)]} ${d} ${y} ${t} GMT${tz}`;
};

const dt = format('2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00');
console.log(dt);
// Jul 18 2013 17:00:00 GMT-05:00
```

There are JavaScript and other library methods that will allow you to convert your datetime string to a `Date` instance and then display it in a specific time zone if you are consistently receiving datetime strings from one or a few specific time zones that are easily identified on the client side. Following are a couple of examples.

[`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) enables you to display a date in a specific time zone but the `options` parameters required to set the time zone are not supported across all browsers (as of the date of this answer). For example (note that parsing of date strings with the `Date` constructor is still discouraged, but most modern browsers will handle an ISO 8601 format string like the one below):

```js
const dt = new Date('2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00');
const ny = dt.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' });
console.log(`Local: ${dt}`);
console.log(`New York: ${ny}`);
```

You could also use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) to display a date in a specific time zone. For example:

```js
const ny = moment('2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00').tz('America/New_York').format();
console.log(`New York: ${ny}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

It is important to note the following when working with datetime strings and time zones in JavaScript. The JavaScript `Date` constructor DOES NOT change the time zone offset. When you create a date from a string using ISO 8601 format as in the question example, [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) does the following:

> Creates a JavaScript Date instance that represents a single moment in
> time. Date objects use a Unix Time Stamp, an integer value that is the
> number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

In other words, JavaScript `Date` instances do not store (or change) time zone offsets. The reason you often see output from a JavaScript `Date` in your local time zone is that [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) is the default method called when you log a `Date` instance to the console (or use various other approaches to output your date). In most browser implementations, this method relies on the browser's local time zone to convert the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC into a string representation of the date.

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if this would help:

```
function goAheadMakeMyDate(s){
  var d = new Date(s);
  // override Date.toString()
  d.toString = function(){ return ''+s; };
  return d;
}

var example = goAheadMakeMyDate("Fri 19 July 2013 12:00:00 GMT");

example.toString() // returns string actually used to construct the date
'Fri 19 July 2013 12:00:00 GMT'

example.toLocaleString()
'Fri Jul 19 2013 08:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)'

1*example // gives seconds since epoch
1374235200000
```

With your input:

```
example = goAheadMakeMyDate('2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00')
{ Thu, 18 Jul 2013 22:00:00 GMT toString: [Function] }
> example.toString()
'2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00'
> example.toLocaleString() // I live in GMT-4
'Thu Jul 18 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)'
> 1*example  // convert to integer date
1374184800000
```

However, if you start modifying this date, the toString will *not* change and will bite you.

Comment: This made my date :-) But it won't work when the date object is modified (by `setHour` or something).

Comment: But did you fire 5 shots, or was that your 6th? Actually, doing this properly would probably require duplicating everything date does...

Answer (score 0):

I have a scenario where date time stamp needs to update only once. In detail I have button in my application and when clicked on it will generate a PDF along with timestamp footer and when refreshed it should not change date time.

For the above scenario I have used localStorage.setItem('','') and getItems. In precise.... when clicked on generate button I have used localStorage.setItem('','') and in the generating footer logic I have used localStorage.getItem('') dats it....

Explanation for above logic:

1. Whenever we are generating I am setting current date time and when generating am calling getItem which will pick the set date time from local storage.
2. This will reset again when clicked on Generate button.

Hope this helps someone in need..... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this

```
new Date('2013-07-18T17:00:00-05:00'.slice(0, 19).replace("T", " "));
```