# AngularJS Display Date in ISO 8601 Time Zone

Tags: angularjs

I have an API that returns ISO 8601 dates with the time zone offset:

- 2016-03-05T06:00:00.000-08:00
- 2016-03-05T08:00:00.000-05:00

Currently the dates are displayed in the browser's time zone when using the Angular date filter:

```
{{scheduled | date : 'medium'}
```

Is it possible to display them in the time zone they come down in (i.e. PST for the first and EST for the last) along with the time zone name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop javascript Date function from changing timezone offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751698/stop-javascript-date-function-from-changing-timezone-offset)

Comment: Several timezones can have the same offset at a given time, and still be diffferent (different DST rules, etc.). An offset is not sufficient to identify a timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to parse the offset from the date (using a regex) then apply it to the date. This can be wrapped into a custom Angular filter that wraps the `date` filter:

```
angular.module('app').filter('datetz', ['$filter', '$window',
  function ($filter) {
    var _ = $window._;
    return function (date, format) {
      // Attempt to extract the +00:00 portion of the date.
      var matches = date.match(/[+-]\d\d:\d\d/);
      var timezone = _.last(matches);

      return $filter('date')(date, format, timezone);
    };
  }
]);

{{'2016-03-05T06:00:00.000-08:00' | datetz : 'medium'}
{{'2016-03-05T06:00:00.000-05:00' | datetz : 'medium'}
```