# Convert string to a DateTime format without converting it to your Local Time

Tags: javascript, datetime

Here's my Scenario: 
I have a value for DateTime in this Format only:
'2017-05-01T07:40:00.000+10:00' 
but need this to convert to a Readable Date Time Format like this: 
eg.  05/01/2017 07:40 AM
- Without Converting it to your Local Time, because if i use

```
var t = "2017-05-01T07:40:00.000+10:00";
var d = new Date(t); //using javascript Date object
var z = moment(t); // or using moment.js:
```

var d and z both have the same output like this: 
Mon May 01 2017 05:40:00 GMT+0800 (Taipei Standard Time)

```
//05/01/2017 05:40 AM
```

it's minus 2 Hour in my Local Timezone GMT +8, but i don't want it to be converted that way. 
i just need the exact Time which is 05/01/2017 07:40 AM
Is there other way to get my desired output in javascript?

Comment: What kind of format is this? The "2017-05-01T07:40:00.000+10:00"

Comment: it's in iso string format,  ISO-standard specification of date and time,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use with `Regex` pattern `/-|:|T/g` for `split()`

```js
var t = "2017-05-01T07:40:00.000+10:00";
var s =t.split(/-|:|T/g).slice(0,5)
var c =parseInt(s[3]) > 12 ? parseInt(s[3])-12 : s[3];
var f =parseInt(s[3]) > 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

console.log(s[1]+'/'+s[2]+'/'+s[0]+'  '+c+':'+s[4]+' '+f);
```

Comment: This is a good answer using regex. But im still looking for other options.

Comment: i need the 12Hour conversion with AM/PM, this solution still in 24Hour Time format

Comment: @alomegah see my updated answer .I was added `AM & PM` code

Comment: well,you're great, using your answer: var t = "2017-05-01T07:40:00.000+10:00";   var s = t.split(/-|:|T/g).slice(0, 5);
 var parseTime = s[1] + '/' + s[2] + '/' + s[0] + '  ' + s[3] + ':' + s[4];

 var newTime = (new Date(parseTime)).toString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt'); -- i used the javascript date object from the parsed datetime from your earlier code, it gives me now the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to this post
[Stop javascript Date function from changing timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751698/stop-javascript-date-function-from-changing-timezone-offset)

It also mentioned a sample on how to use 'moment' to pinpoint the datetime to the timezone you want to show (GMT+10).

Answer (score 0):

I think so this will help you.

```
var t = "2017-05-01T07:40:00.000Z";
var d = new Date(t); //using javascript Date object
```

Comment: var t is already in string format.  the same as what i wrote above

Comment: but Check that I have added Z at the end of string Instead of +10:00

Comment: yes you r right we don't need to convert it in string.

Comment: sorry but the input format always have a timezone, it can't be changed with your given input.