# Converting date format javascript database

Tags: javascript, date-conversion

I have a database field with a date as value, it is inserted by an API (which is hosted external) and gives the format **yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00**. How can I convert this to a **dd-MM-yyyy** (no time) format when the value is recalled on the page?
EG. *1964-05-11T00:00:00* has to be displayed as *11-05-1964*

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840972/convert-string-to-a-datetime-format-without-converting-it-to-your-local-time/43841273#43841273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date formatt of the API is consistent, you could do this:

```
function formattDate(str) {
   return str.split('T')[0].split('-').reverse().join('-')
}
```

That's the quickest solution. But if the formatt is not consistent, that is another case.

Answer (score 1):

---

```js
console.log(convertDate('1964-05-11T00:00:00'));
function convertDate(inputFormat) {
  function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
  var d = new Date(inputFormat);
  return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('-');
}
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package: [date-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-format).

You will be able to do something like that:

```
var format = require('date-format');
format('dd-MM-yyyy', new Date());
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Better You can use js library

Source:
https://momentjs.com/
https://momentjs.com/docs/

> Example(demo):

http://www.somelesson.blogspot.com/2016/06/momentjs-changing-locales-locally.html