# Timezone conversions in outlook addin

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am developing an addin for outlook appointments, where `Office.context.mailbox.item.start` gives Start date time of current appointment in the client Machine local timezone. I can convert it to UTC easily.

But problem comes then, if user has set his timezone in exchange to PST and opening the addin on a machine which has local timezone as IST `Office.context.mailbox.item.start` it will again return the IST. How can convert this IST to PST when I all know about target timezone is it's name like "pacific standard time"? Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if you used the Moment JS. However, you could try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751698/stop-javascript-date-function-from-changing-timezone-offset

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want a way to know which timezone the user set in Exchange, so that you convert the given time to that particular timezone?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT if yes to your comment, then what is the answer ?

Comment: @InfoÁsith In our API we give you the timezone of the client in: Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.timeZone. On OWA this timezone is the timezone setup when you created the OWA account.  You may want to take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/tips-for-handling-date-values-in-outlook-add-ins and convertToLocalClientTime. 

One thing that the API does not provide is the timezone of the start property. That is always provided in UTC.

Comment: If you need to convert from two times, and all you have is the timezone name, you will probably need to load another JS library or come up with your own solution.