# Displaying Date and Time in JavaScript without timezone conversion

Tags: javascript, datetime

In my application there is a requirement to display date times in different time zones. All these timestamps are stored in the database in UTC.

If I send the UTC date time to client and display using JavaScript, it automatically converts it to the client's time zone.

For example:

```
//the string is what I receive from the server
var date = new Date('2019-05-03T09:30:00.000+05:30');
document.write(date.toLocaleString("en-US"));
```

displays `5/2/2019, 11:00:00 PM` in the browser which is in the Central Time Zone.

What if I do not want this automatic change, and just want to display the date and time that I received from the server?

I know I can get the offset from the `date` object, but then I have to do additional processing to display the same value that I already got from the server!

Comment: Do you want to display it in the time zone that you specified, or do you want to display it in UTC?

Comment: I want to just display in the timezone that it was received from the server, which can change. I mean in this case it is +5.30 in other cases it can EST, CST, Etc.

Comment: It's a bit complicated, especially if you want to handle if the timezone is in a text-string like 'EST'. If it always was specified in an ISO8901 time format, it can be handled by extracting the time zone from the string, and then manipulate the date object.

Comment: Maybe you can find what you want with https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop javascript Date function from changing timezone offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751698/stop-javascript-date-function-from-changing-timezone-offset)